# Heroku ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: error rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my rails app but getting this error:

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (<) (line: 44009
, col: 4, pos: 1761230)
remote:        Error
remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:2659:11936)
remote:        at js_error (<eval>:2659:12155)
remote:        at croak (<eval>:2659:20622)
remote:        at token_error (<eval>:2659:20759)
remote:        at unexpected (<eval>:2659:20847)
remote:        at expr_atom (<eval>:2659:29141)
remote:        at maybe_unary (<eval>:2659:31652)
remote:        at expr_ops (<eval>:2660:404)
remote:        at maybe_conditional (<eval>:2660:496)
remote:        at maybe_assign (<eval>:2660:939)
remote:        at expression (<eval>:2660:1252)
remote:        at simple_statement (<eval>:2659:24162)
remote:        at <eval>:2659:22067new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2659:11936)
remote:        js_error ((execjs):2659:12155)
remote:        croak ((execjs):2659:20622)
remote:        token_error ((execjs):2659:20759)
remote:        unexpected ((execjs):2659:20847)
remote:        expr_atom ((execjs):2659:29141)
remote:        maybe_unary ((execjs):2659:31652)
remote:        expr_ops ((execjs):2660:404)
remote:        maybe_conditional ((execjs):2660:496)
remote:        maybe_assign ((execjs):2660:939)
remote:        expression ((execjs):2660:1252)
remote:        simple_statement ((execjs):2659:24162)
remote:        (execjs):2659:22067
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:47:in `rescue in block in
 call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:44:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'

remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_p
rocessors'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors
'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_depend
ency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in ini
tialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in log
ical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:225:in `block in stat_tree'

remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `block in stat_direc
tory'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:224:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'

remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:168:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 level
s) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 level
s) in define'
remote:        V8::Error: Unexpected token: operator (<)
remote:        at js_error (<eval>:2659:12155)
remote:        at croak (<eval>:2659:20622)
remote:        at token_error (<eval>:2659:20759)
remote:        at unexpected (<eval>:2659:20847)
remote:        at expr_atom (<eval>:2659:29141)
remote:        at maybe_unary (<eval>:2659:31652)
remote:        at expr_ops (<eval>:2660:404)
remote:        at maybe_conditional (<eval>:2660:496)
remote:        at maybe_assign (<eval>:2660:939)
remote:        at expression (<eval>:2660:1252)
remote:        at simple_statement (<eval>:2659:24162)
remote:        at <eval>:2659:22067
remote:        at <eval>:2659:21493
remote:        at <eval>:2660:1595
remote:        at parse (<eval>:2660:1804)
remote:        at <eval>:19:26
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:45:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'

remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_p
rocessors'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors
'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_depend
ency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in ini
tialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in log
ical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:225:in `block in stat_tree'

remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `block in stat_direc
tory'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:224:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'

remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:168:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 level
s) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_7c95f59f6c8a8dee3c57db5de06a84d6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.
2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 level
s) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to taponomics.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/taponomics.git
```

**my application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//

//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-1.11.1
//= require jquery.easing.min

//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'public_activity'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem "autoprefixer-rails"
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'pry-rails', :group => :development
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jekyll'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre2'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'byebug'
end

 gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I am not understanding anything, why am getting this error, i had deployed other projects on heroku but had never got something like this.

Comment: Probably there is a problem in one of the required JS asset files. I'd try to comment out each required JS library, one at a time, to narrow the problem down. Also it seams to me that you require jquery twice in your `application.js`?